# None of the boot menu options work on an Intel NUC?

Tags: boot

This is an older NUC. I'm trying to boot from USB, but no matter which F- option I select, it always boots from the OS. Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: Check to see if `Secure Boot` is enabled.... disable it... once disabled youcan test if your boot device works. If not you need to enable the CSM (Compatibility Support Module) to enable legacy boot options.

Comment: What is an `F- option`? Is it something NUC specific?